# Save changes Vagrantfile on file.box

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, packer, vagrant-provision

After I created my 'Vagrantfile' from my file 'test.box', I'm going to edit the file 'Vagrantfile' inserting for example:

```
config.vm.provision: shell, path: './test.sh'
```

Done this, how do I save the changes to the file test.box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the question, but let me explain:

Boxes are the package format for Vagrant environments, you can read more about boxes from the documentation (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html)

From this box, vagrant will create a VM using the Vagrantfile that you have defined. If this Vagrantfile defines provisioning steps, those will be run when you initialized the vm (first time you run `vagrant up`, you can also define a provisioner to run every time you start the vm)

To run a provisioner every time you start the vm, you need to have

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "./test.sh", :run => 'always'
```

Note when you run `vagrant halt` to stop the VM, you only shutdown the system so everything you have install remains on the vm, next time you run `vagrant up` all the things you have created in the VM will be available. 
`vagrant destroy` does completely wipe out all files from vm so when you run `vagrant up` after, the vm will be created from scratch

so now, if you have done changes to the vm and would like to use that as a new box, you need to **package** the vm using `vagrant package`, you can read more about [package](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html). This will produce a new box that you can use in your new Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to run a file shell every time I run the command 'vagrant up / vagrant provision'.

To do this I did the following:

1. I created (with Packer) the file 'test.box'
2. With the command 'init test.box vagrant' I create Vagrantfile.

In this step, I edit the file Vagrantfile inputting, for example:

```
config.vm.provision: shell, path: './file.sh'
```

So that every time I run the command 'vagrant up / vagrant provision' he performs "file.sh".
My problem is that I do not understand how I can save this change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.
You may take your vagrantfile, make all needed changes
and add additional section to your packer.json file:

`"post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "vagrant",
      "keep_input_artifact": false,
      "compression_level": 1,
      "vagrantfile_template": "MyCustom.vagrantfile",
      "output": "box/box_with_custom_vagrantfile.box"
    }
  ]`